# On AWS lambda failure adding retry logic if still fail send alert

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I want to design AWS lambda in manner where if its failed then lambda should attempt to retry for given no of time & if after those many attempts it still fail then alert user.

I tied to configure AWS CloudWatch alarm for failure but looks like user is alert on first failure of lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about using SQS for the DLQ(Dead Letter Queue)?

You can make fault tolerant architecture using SQS and Lambda together.

Briefly saying, you can make two functions at lambda.

Function1: the first one which is triggered by initial trigger and do it's job. If it fails, it will go to SQS.

Function2 : this is triggered by SQS polling, which means that this function runs when there is a message in SQS queue. It reads SQS message so the event handler should be little bit different.